# non breaking space in Antenna House

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I'm not an expert, that's why asking for help.
I have a problem with getting in the Antenna House preview - non breaking space (hard space).
The XML document file contains non braking space (U+00A0).
File is encoded in utf-8

Tried to add a parameter to the configuration file as below, but unfortunately it does not work (preview still shows normal spaces)

Antenna House ver. 6.4
Does anyone know how to configure Antenna House for the view to show hard spaces?
I will be grateful for any help ;-)

```
<formatter-config>
<xslt-settings 
justify-nbsp="true"
  </xslt-settings>
</formatter-config>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CWmC.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFyhf.png)

Comment: The tag is malformed and/or missing a > on xslt-settings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, even in AH Formatter V6.4, `axf:justify-nbsp`/`justify-nbsp` is an extension property, not a formatter option setting.  I can't find anything about it ever being an option setting.  As such, you just use it in your document/stylesheet just like any other inherited property (though you haven't said whether you're using XSL-FO or CSS).

Secondly, AH Formatter does not have an option to make non-breaking spaces visible.  You could, however, use XSLT to put an `fo:inline`/`span` around every non-breaking space and give that element a background color.

---

Add `axf:justify-nbsp="false"` to your XSL-FO:

```
<fo:block space-after="1em">podstawowa opieka zdrowotna lorem1 ipsum1 lorem2 ipsum2&#xA0;lorem3 ipsum3 fdg123b XXXX</fo:block>
<fo:block axf:justify-nbsp="false">podstawowa opieka zdrowotna lorem1 ipsum1 lorem2 ipsum2&#xA0;lorem3 ipsum3 fdg123b XXXX</fo:block>
```

[image: With and without axf:justify-nbsp="false"]

Since `axf:justify-nbsp` is an inherited property (see hhttps://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.justify-nbsp), if you want it to apply to the whole document, you could instead put it on the `fo:root`: i.e., `<fo:root axf:justify-nbsp="false">`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :-)

I take the document file as below::
Document: here I am giving my document in XML format
Stylesheet: here gives the model file in XSL format

I do not know if I have expressed myself precisely, but I mean a hard space
after loading the document it was included in the view.
I mean, if [here] is a hard space, that's a word "is" will not go to the next paragraph in case of justification.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a minimal example of your XSL-FO and a screenshot of what is wrong with the formatted example.

Comment: Screen is attached to my question ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for every tips!
Excuse me, but I'm not very good at this - Please look on my second screen.

Comment: `<fo:root axf:justify-nbsp="false">`. Since it is an inherited property, the value is inherited by every descendant FO (unless you also set it on a descendant, that is).

Comment: You're welcome. You now have the option of accepting the answer so that it gets a green tick/check mark.